# OpenVPN Access Server - How Do You Route All Client Traffic Through The VPN?

Tags: openvpn

I currently have an EC2 server with OpenVPN installed that I spun up using the official **OpenVPN Access Server AMI**.

I went through the OpenVPN setup process with all default values selected and I've been able to connect to my instance using the Windows client I downloaded from the VPN server.

My purpose is to use the VPN server to connect to the internet.  I will be going to a country where certain websites and services are blocked and need the VPN server to bypass the firewalls in place.  I do not plan on using the VPN server to access any private networks.

I have updated my OpenVPN Access Server settings to force it to route all internet traffic and to have its clients use the same DNS servers as the access server host:

[image]

I have also enabled IP forwarding on my EC2 instance with the following command:

```
echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

With the above settings, I am unable to connect to the internet when I am connected to my VPN.  If I turn off *Should client internet traffic be routed through the VPN*, I can connect to the internet, but I would be connected through my original ISP IP address.

What else do you need to do here to enable OpenVPN to route all internet traffic?

Comment: Can you check after connecting to vpn server, if the client routing table get successfully updated? If you don't see a default route pointing to the vpn server, then there is a problem.

Comment: Any news on this? I have a same problem here. btw as @Bruce mentioned you need to disable "Change Source/Destination Check" on your instance.

Comment: Any updates?  I'm having the same issue.  Man, openvpn has poor, terse documentation!

Answer (score 1):

On AWS Web Console, select your OpenVPN Access Server instance, then select "Actions", then select "Networking" then disable "Change Source/Destination Check"

Comment: Same problem here. Well that is an extra step that should be done, but even with disabling that option I can't connect to internet through my OpenVPN server.